# ahk: how to read non txt file and save infos to variables?

Tags: autohotkey

i have a replay file from a game (world of tanks)  and i want to read infos from it and store them to variables.

when i open the file with notepad there seems to be some xml "code" witch contains some of the infos i want and then there starts the replay file data so its only gibberish. example: http://pastebin.com/faBPUn1d

i tried to extract the first line with FileReadLine but the variable contains only crap :(

how can i read the file with ahk, store infos like "damageDealt": 9321 to a variable? 
thank you for your help

Comment: what's the file extension? xml? json?

Comment: filnames are like this: 14467613928363_ussr_Object263_45_north_america.wotreplay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JSON data inside a binary file so use [FileOpen](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileOpen.htm) function to open it.

There are two JSON blocks and each one is prefixed by its length (`NumGet` or `File.ReadUInt` or similar to the rescue) so you can use it extract the block and pass it to [AutoHotkey-JSON parser](https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-JSON).

And then you will be able to access the object hierarchically or enumerate it like any object:
`result.personal["14337"].details["(9291360, 7169)"].damageDealt`.

Example:

```lisp
#include JSON.ahk ; download from https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-JSON

; read the data
f := fileOpen("14473423299267_usa_A02_M2_lt_thepit.wotreplay", "r")
f.seek(8)
data1 := JSON.load(f.read(f.readUInt()))
data2 := JSON.load(f.read(f.readUInt()))
f.close()

; write the data as pretty-formatted JSON
f := fileOpen("data1.json", "w"), f.write(JSON.dump(data1,,"`t")), f.close()
f := fileOpen("data2.json", "w"), f.write(JSON.dump(data2,,"`t")), f.close()

; load the first item of 'data2[1].personal' object into personalInfo
data2[1].personal._NewEnum().Next(k, personalInfo)

msgbox % "playerName: " data1.playerName "`n"
       . "dateTime: " data1.dateTime "`n"
       . "mapName: " data1.mapName "`n"
       . "`n"
       . "damageDealt: " personalInfo.damageDealt "`n"
```

Comment: hey thank you for your input - i consider myself a scripting noob and i just learned what json files are :( would you mind to be a little more specific? i think i figured out that in the replay files are more then one json data i had a look at them with http://json.parser.online.fr/ well my problem ist that i dont understand how to properly open a binary file and 2. if i manage to open it how to use a json parser like https://github.com/cocobelgica/AutoHotkey-JSON

Comment: well if you could motivate yourself, that would be awsome :) here is an example file: http://wotreplays.com/site/download/2271137

Comment: @user2325701, done. The script creates `data1.json` and `data2.json` files, which you can use to see the structure. You'll probably have to read about objects and arrays in AHK as well as get acquainted with JSON syntax.